# percona prm debian lenny

Tags: mysql, debian, percona, lenny

I try  to setup the Percona PRM with Corosync and Pacemaker on Debian Lenny.

I followed this how to : [PRM Percona Replication Manager](https://github.com/jayjanssen/Percona-Pacemaker-Resource-Agents/blob/master/doc/PRM-setup-guide.rst#to-view-andor-edit-the-configuration)

But pacemaker is not able to start MySQL properly. I mean that it try to launch it and after few seconds stop it.

It's look like that the issue come from the check_slave in MySQL script but the error is not really explicit...

A quick look in the part of the log with the error:

```
Oct 16 11:29:26 mysqltest01 mysql[12107]: ERROR: check_slave invoked on an instance that is not a replication slave.
Oct 16 11:29:26 mysqltest01 mysql[12107]: ERROR: /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/heartbeat/.ocf-shellfuncs: line 330: -q: command not found
Oct 16 11:29:26 mysqltest01 mysql[12107]: ERROR: Failed to select from 
Oct 16 11:29:26 mysqltest01 mysql[12107]: ERROR: Failed initial monitor action
```

Impossible to understand why the ocf-shellfuncs doesn't work well.

Comment: You're missing the directory  /usr/lib/ocf/lib.